# Using QueueBackgroundWorkItem correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have couple of questions to see if I am using QueueBackgroundWorkItem correctly:

In _ViewStart.cshtml I am calling a method to cache a collection. My thought was to use QueueBackgroundWorkItem so the HTTP request would continue while the cache method executes in background. Is this correct thinking?

Example pseudo-code:

```
[_ViewStart.cshtml] 
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct => SetCache("StringVal1", "StringVal2"));


[Method]
public void SetCache(string param1, string param2)
{
    // Do some stuff....
}
```

Secondly, do you have to pass the cancellation token to method when using QueueBackgroundWorkItem? Or only if you need it within your call?

Thanks!

Comment: A cache should return almost instantly so there should be no need for async work. You only have to pass a Cancellation Token if you want to be able to cancel your "do some stuff". Executing a long running `SetCache` method on every page load sounds weird to me.

Comment: @Charles In the example it may take some time to process the data to cache. It would be doing a check to see if cache exists in the method (expires 60 minutes) so would really only run when expires. However, needs to check on regular basis to confirm cache exists so I was think having in viewstart would be best place. Thoughts?

Comment: Usually you just build your cache into your `GetData()` function. `If (cacheTooOld) RefeshCache and return item, else return item from cache`. If you want it to be available beforehand then a timer might be the better option than to rely on ViewStart.